# Everything works correct here. How we can check "title" is in dictionary , if I did not added or appended nothing but it adds itself

Tags: dictionary, key

```
import csv
 
titles = {}

with open("sample4.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    for row in reader:
        title = row["GameNumber"].strip().upper()

        if title in titles:
            titles[title] += 1
        else:
            titles[title] = 1
for title in titles:
    print(title, titles[title])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wish to replace you `if`/`else` block with something shorter?

You can use:

```
tiltes[title] = titles.get(title, 0) + 1
```

Comment: no, I don't want to change anythinh here. I want to know how it populates titles[]

Comment: `titles` is a dictionary (empty at the beginning). You can add new key/value pairs with `title[key]  = value`